# regex getting number from tags

Tags: php, regex, expression

I am trying get this number which is between tags `<< >>`

```
333333
```

from

```
string = "my subject <<my-support-id=333333>>"
```

Can you give any advise as I am not getting anywhere

I am trying to get this using `preg_match` function in php.

Comment: Seems like simple string manipulation might be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

How about the regex

```
/<<[^\d]+(\d+)>>/
```

- `[^\d]+` Negated character class. would match anything other than digits, `\d`
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1 will contain the digits within the `<< >>`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lX0xE7/1)

**Test**

```
preg_match("/<<[^\d]+(\d+)>>/", "my subject <<my-support-id=333333>>",$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
=> 333333
```

**OR**

```
/<<[^=]+=(\d+)>>/
```

**Test**

```
preg_match ( "/<<[^=]+=(\d+)>>/", "my subject <<my-support-id=333333>>",$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
=> 333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\=([0-9]+)>/','my subject <<my-support-id=333333>>', $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $out[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this -

```
$string = "my subject <<my-support-id=333333>>";
$pattern = '/\d+/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And the output would be `Array ( [0] => 333333 )`

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5591-jeh6)